# Storing data client data

Tags: php, client

I am making a little light weight 2 way chat client, however I am unsure how to store the data my options are:

- JSON
- XML
- Text File
- Database

I will be using PHP and Ajax, which would be scalable and small in size?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to develop a Chat client, performance here is key.

i would suggest the following (my personal favorite):

### Server Side

1. Store Data in **Database** for a nice balance between performance and flexibility
2. **PHP** page that interacts as an interface between the **Database** and the client via **JSON** since it's lightweight and therefore fast

### Client Side

1. **AJAX** based GUI that can parse and send **JSON** data.
2. **(Optional)** use a JavaScript framework to help you with #1, like jQuery/ExtJS/etc'

If you would like to choose this set up I would also suggest you at least familiarize yourself with the other options so you can decide for your own.

Good Luck!

Comment: +1 @BigFatBaby Great Solution, if i had answer it before you, it would be exactly same. So i did not repeated it. I vote for this answer.